# How to enable a profile / permission set to access a connected app on a scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, connected-apps

Connected Apps are global for all Salesforce , so they do not need to be replicated on scratch orgs: when the user access them for the first time, they are installed on the org.

When a connected app has policy

> Admin-approved users are pre-authorized

it is necessary to configure a profile or a permission set to allow the user to pre-authorize it. How do you do so in SalesforceDX?